# Email Notification for test results by using Python in Robot Framework

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

We are using ROBOT framework to execute automation test cases.
Could anyone please guide me to write script for e-mail notification of test results.

Note:
I have e-mail server details.

Regards,
-kranti

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom library for send email.

More details in [official documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#keyword-names)

I did something similar, I based on this [article](http://izheyi.com/2016/06/08/Robot-Framework-Establish-Customize-Library-Through-Implement-Send-Email-Function/) to create the library.

an example of the function in python file:

```
import smtplib
from io import StringIO
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

from email import encoders
import os


def send_mail_no_attachment(server, from_user, from_password, to, subject, text):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    msg['From'] = from_user
    msg['To'] = to
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

    mailServer = smtplib.SMTP(server)
    mailServer.ehlo()
    mailServer.starttls()
    mailServer.ehlo()
    mailServer.login(from_user, from_password)
    mailServer.sendmail(from_user, to, msg.as_string())
    mailServer.close()
```

call the function in robot file:

```
*** Test Cases ***
example mail
    send mail no attachment  ${SMTP_SERVER}  ${USER}  ${PASS}  ${mail}  ${subject}  ${text}
```

If you are not very expert with the robot framework, define only the function, do not define the class, and you can call this function within your algorithm as a keyword.

Answer (score 2):

I use smtplib and MIMEText

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

class EmailClient():

    def __init__(self, my_address):
        self.my_address = my_address

    def send(self, message, subject, user, email):

        header = "Hello " + str(user) + ",\n\n"
        footer = "\n\n-Your Boss"
        msg = MIMEText(header + message + footer)

        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg['From'] = self.my_address
        msg['To'] = email

        s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
        s.sendmail(self.my_address, [email], msg.as_string())
        s.quit()

EClient = EmailClient("MyEmail@University.edu")
EClient.send("This is a test Email", "Test Subject", "John Doe", "jdoe@University.edu")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Could you please let me know how we can import test results from Robot frame work by using this code.

Answer (score 2):

you can use jenkins to run your Robot Framework Testcases. There is a auto-generated mail option in jenkins to send mail with Test results.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar requirement so using python file I have achieved requirement (need to execute .py file after robot execution)

Project [link](https://github.com/adiralashiva8/robotframework-email-result) and [Readme.md](https://github.com/adiralashiva8/robotframework-email-result/blob/master/README.md)

**How to send email after test execution**

1. Copy robotemail.py to file
2. Create a bat file (which executes robot command and .py file in sequence)

   robot test.robot &&
   python robotemail.py
3. Execute bat file
4. Email will be sent to recipients